# C++ Class is not being Initialized

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

In C++ you can't include Header Files in each other because of recursion. So you have to make use of Predefined Classes right? So I want to get the **value of num in C.hpp and print it out in B.hpp**.

C Class gets initialized before B Class which is expected.

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnW1M.png)

But when I'm trying to call A::instance->c it is **NULL**!

[B Class with unitialized C Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVFBh.png)

**A.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
class C;                        // PREDEFINED CLASS
class B;                        // PREDEFINED CLASS
class A {
public:
    inline static A* instance;
    C* c{ 0 };
    B* b{ 0 };

    A() {
        instance = this;
    }

    void start(B* b,C* c) {
        this->c = c;
        this->b = b;
    }
};
```

**B.hpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "C.hpp"

class B {
public:

    void call() {
        if (A::instance->c)
            std::cout << "C Num: " << A::instance->c->num << "\n";
        else std::cout << "C Class is NULL!\n";
    }

    B() {
        std::cout << "B init!\n";
        call();
    }
};
```

**C.hpp**

```
class C {
public:
    int num = 0;

    C() {
        std::cout << "C init!\n";
        num = 69;
    }
};
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "C.hpp"

void main() {
    A a;
    a.start(new B(), new C());
}
```

Comment: In `a.start(new B(), new C())`, obviously constructors of `B` and `C` have to run before `start` can be called - but `B`'s constructor expects `A::instance` to already have a valid `C` pointer. You could salvage this design by having two separate setters: create `C` first, set it in `a`, then construct and set `B`.

Comment: please do not use images of code. I am not able to understand the question because one has to switch between the images and the code in the question to get what you are asking.

Comment: Why do you think `A::instance->c` should already be set during `B`'s constructor ?

Comment: Why don't you have `A`'s constructor create `B` and `C` instances (in the right order)? Yes, you cannot implement such a constructor in `A.hpp` - but you can in `A.cpp`, which could happily include all three headers if necessary.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the shown code is not the real code that has the alleged issue, for the following reasons: 1) no modern C++ compiler will accept a `void main`. 2) If you follow the inclusion chain, `C.hpp` gets included twice, once from `B.hpp` and and then directly from `Source.cpp`, this will result in a duplicate class definition from every self-respecting C++ compiler.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I posted the whole code, the image just shows that it's null in the debugger

Comment: "But when I'm trying to call A::instance->c it is NULL!" requires me to look at the image and understand how the code in the image relates to the code in the question. Nevermind, after some time I think I got it, but I would still say that without the images your question is incomplete, while they arent necessary for the question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik For me the code runs using visual studio 2019

Comment: Ok, so that only goes to show how badly broken Microsoft's C++ compiler is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C Class gets initialized before B Class which is expected.

No, it's not expected, the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

But even if that's the case as in your example output, you've created new C class object, and now you are trying to create B class object and during that, you are trying to access `A::instance->c` which **is not set yet**.

You set `c` for class A object in the `start` function, but you are still evaluating its parameters during this calls and didn't reach the actual body of the function.

Thus, the `c` in the class A is the default 0 as you set by `C* c{ 0 };`.